# SQL: How to get the original sorting when joining two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables

The first looks like this:

```
Name|Sir Name|Adress
Max1|Musterma|Muster Street
Max2|Musterma|Muster Street
Max3|Musterma|Muster Street
Max4|Musterma|Muster Street
Max5|Musterma|Muster Street
```

The second looks like this:

```
Name|Money
Max3|50.00
Max1|40.00
Max3|43.00
Max2|77.00
Max3|18.00
Max1|97.00
Max1|87.00
```

I want to use Left Join and make an Output like this:

```
Max1|Musterma|Muster Street|40.00
Max1|Musterma|Muster Street|97.00
Max1|Musterma|Muster Street|87.00
Max2|Musterma|Muster Street|77.00
Max3|Musterma|Muster Street|50.00
Max3|Musterma|Muster Street|43.00
Max3|Musterma|Muster Street|18.00
Max4|Musterma|Muster Street|
Max5|Musterma|Muster Street|
```

What I get is like:

```
Max3|Musterma|Muster Street|50.00
Max1|Musterma|Muster Street|40.00
Max3|Musterma|Muster Street|43.00
Max2|Musterma|Muster Street|77.00
Max3|Musterma|Muster Street|18.00
Max1|Musterma|Muster Street|97.00
Max1|Musterma|Muster Street|87.00
Max4|Musterma|Muster Street|
Max5|Musterma|Muster Street|
```

What I get is sorted after the position of the entries of the second (right) table.

But I want to get the list sorted

1. after the position of the user in the first
2. after the position of the money in the second

Can anyone tell me what i further have to write?

Comment: Post the SQL you've written so far. All you need to do is add an `order by` to the end of it.

Comment: do you have any column that will determine how are the records from table2 be ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `order by` clause to the end of your SQL. It will look something like this:

```
order by Table1.Name, Table2.Money
```

Comment: I don't want to order alphabetically.
I want to order after the position of the first table.
Max 1 is the first entry in the first table - so I want Max1 and his money-penalties to be the first lines in the output

Comment: Tables don't have inherent order. The on-disk order of rows can change without notice, and you should never rely on it. Sounds like you need to add an `order int` or `inserted datetime` column to specify the order of your rows explicitly, then order by that.

Comment: You mean, the two tables both have to have a column called "ID" where the data positions are number from 1 to ... so that i can sort the output after them?

Comment: Yup, that would work. If you want your rows to be ordered, you have to `order by` something.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an order by clause as follows:

```
select name
     , sir_name
     , address
     , money
from   table1
left join table2 on (...)
ORDER BY name, money
```

I just guessed the name of your tables and columns since you haven't supplied them =)

Comment: the problem of your solution is that the results are sorted alphabetically.
but i want to have the first position in the first table on top of my output lines and the last position of my first position on the bottom of my output lines.